# Angular - extract o read value from method and save it to later use

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to save the value from the coords, lat n lon, for using them in other methods inside this .TS file. 
But when i reach the `"let x = pos.coords;"` part, it gave me an error of 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'LAT' of null".
seems that im losing the value or i cant access the LAT n LOG variables to save them

inside my "menu.component.ts"

```
  public LAT:any;
  public LON:any;

  ngOnInit() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
    function success(pos: { coords: any; }) {
      let x = pos.coords;
      this.LAT = x.latitud;
      this.LON = x.longitud;
    }
  }
```

and, when save the value on LAT n LOG, how can i call them on other methods...
like `this.LAT` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue with your code is using `this` in the function change your code to below

```
  ngOnInit() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos: { coords: any }) => {
      let x = pos.coords;
      this.LAT = x.latitude;
      this.LON = x.longitude;
      console.log(this.LAT, this.LON);
    }, error => { 
       console.error(error);
    } );
  }
```

Comment: it ask for a comma " , " just before the first pos. do i need to import something?

Comment: shouldn't be, there must be some error on other part of your code

Comment: that does the trick. is correct now. thanks. but whe i try to read LAT or LON in other methos whit ```this.LAT``` it reads as undefined

Comment: you need to wait until values are set, this is async code, if you add console log in the place you are reading and in the place you are setting you will see the sequence

Comment: i call with a ```window.alert(this.LAT);``` but no value are set. i let roll by some time but no value are set. so, what do i need to use, to set the value instantly so i can read it in other method

Comment: I added a console log, to check if the values has ever been set or not

Comment: throws 2 undefined

Comment: you have typo in your code, you missed letter `e` on both
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates